# Why Does Sample Size Affect the Value of F-Statistic We Require to Reject the Null Hypothesis of No Relationship?

Tags: multiple-regression, sample-size, f-statistic

In studying for multiple linear regression, I came across a comment that says that given a large sample, a F-statistic slightly larger than 1 could suggest there is some relationship between the response and the predictors. While, for a small sample size, we require a larger F-statistic to reject the no-relationship hypothesis.

What is the mathematical/algebraic reason for this? Also, is there a intuitive explanation for this?

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically, it's because that is how the F statistic is distributed under the null hypothesis. I tried to find the formula for the critical values of F at different numerator and denominator degrees of freedom, but I didn't succeed. Sorry. But there are tables and calculators of the values available on the web.

Intuitively, F is an effect size, and what you ask is true for any effect size measure. Why? Because when strange things happen in a small sample, it's less unusual than when they happen in large samples.

Suppose you have a notion that blond people are taller than brown haired people. So, you get some blonds and brunettes and measure them. You find that the average blond person is 3 cm taller than the average brunette!  Hooray!

Well, unless you only got two of each group. It's easy for that difference to show up by chance in groups of two, even if the null is true.   But if you find that difference with 200 people in each group, that's much more interesting.